# How to Download Media Library images from sitecore to local folder

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6

I tried this code, but not working From Using Statement.

```
var database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
var images = database.SelectItems("/sitecore/media library/Corsair/Home Page/*");
foreach (var image in images)
     {
       var mediaItem = (MediaItem)image;
       var media = MediaManager.GetMedia(mediaItem);
       var stream = media.GetStream();
       using (var targetStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(@"F:\folder", image.Name + ".jpeg" )))
       {
           stream.CopyTo(targetStream);
           targetStream.Flush();
       }
     }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Any exception?

Comment: It is not working from "Using" Statement...we cant view the errors in sitecore..

Comment: Nothing in log files? How do you know it's not working from "using"? Does the user which IIS process is running as has write permissions to the `f:\folder`?

Comment: the images variable contains the list of images, when trying to write those images to the local folder using OpenWrite() method, I'm not succeeding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example which works for me:

```
//button to trigger event on front end
<asp:Button ID="myButton" Text="Export Images" OnClick="ExportMedia" runat="server" />
```

in code behind

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Resources.Media;

namespace YourNamespace
{
public partial class MediaLibraryExporter : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void ExportMedia(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var database = Database.GetDatabase("master");
        var images = database.SelectItems("/sitecore/media library/Images/Branches/descendant::*[@@templatekey='jpeg']");

        foreach (var image in images)
        {
            var mediaItem = (MediaItem)image;
            var media = MediaManager.GetMedia(mediaItem);
            var stream = media.GetStream();

            using (var targetStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine("Your output folder location", image.Name + ".jpeg" )))
            {
                stream.CopyTo(targetStream);
                targetStream.Flush();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Goose works fairly well, but if you have a lot of images (200+) in a folder, you will need to use a Sitecore Fast Query instead.

Simply add "fast:" to the beginning of the SelectItems query so that line ends up looking like:

```
var images = database.SelectItems("fast:/sitecore/media library/Images/Branches/descendant::*[@@templatekey='jpeg']");
```